# Click seems to be blocked by blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directives that handle the validation using a bind to the blur event, as seen on this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/avEJ2xfLfz6ihM3DwLyB?p=preview (The valid input for the first field is an email address, second field is 'yes')

The validation works, but in order to trigger the allowValidation() function sometimes you have to click the submit button twice.

I narrowed this down to some interaction between the onblur and the button; presumably if you have an onblur even on one of the two text fields still waiting to blur the button only handles the blur and not the click.

Is there a way to make it handle click and not blur maybe? I'm calling the validation in the click too.

Answer (score 0):

In my trials, I did not find any issue with your code. However, if you really have a scenario in which the blur and the click of the button seem to conflict, you could have a variable that  is set when the validity is being triggered and reset once the validation is completed.

Basically, in your linking function on the directive, have the following:

```
//Keeps track of the validation being active
var validationInProgress = false;

function dovalidation () {
    validationInProgress = true;
    //Validation code goes here
    if (EMAIL_REGX.test(elm.val())) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('emails', true);
    } else {
        ctrl.$setValidity('emails', false);
    }

    //Set this after validations are over
    //Should be the last statement in this function
    validationInProgress = false;
}
```

Once this is done, each time there is call to `dovalidation()`, before calling check if there is already a validation in progress - if not, then only call.

```
elm.bind('blur', function () {
    if (!validationInProgress) {
        scope.$apply(dovalidation);
    }
});

scope.$on('kickOffValidations', function () {
    if (!validationInProgress) {
        dovalidation();
    }
});
```

EDIT: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4E6WlBpWQ5NfSrJHrBMZ?p=preview) code with the above update.

Comment: Not sure what's going on then; I had a different plunkr which didn't seem to work but I didn't save it correctly apparently, *and* I can't reproduce the problem now. Will have to look at it again on monday, thanks for your help so far.